# Solve :- $\frac{x - n}{m} - \frac{x - m}{n} = \frac{m}{n}$ for all $mn \neq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, roots, problem-solving

> Solve :- $\frac{x - n}{m} - \frac{x - m}{n} = \frac{m}{n}$ for all $mn \neq 0$

**What I Tried** :- I just simplified the expression step by step and got :-

$$=> \frac{n(x - n) - m(x - m)}{mn} = \frac{m}{n}$$

$$=> n(x - n) - m(x - m) = m^2$$

$$=> nx - n^2 - mx + m^2 = m^2$$

$$=> nx - n^2 - mx = 0$$

From here I don't know how to proceed in a good way. Can anyone help?

Comment: So I think you're supposed to solve for $x$, right? What you have in the last line is just a linear equation for $x$ ...

Comment: It's just given :- Solve the equation , maybe we have to find the solutions for $m,n,x$ all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now $$(n-m)x=n^2.$$
If $n=m$, so $n=0$, which is impossible.

But for $n\neq m$ we obtain:
$$x=\frac{n^2}{n-m}.$$
Id est, we got the following answer for $mn\neq0$.

If $m=n$, so our equation has no roots.

if $n\neq m$ we obtain: $\left\{\dfrac{n^2}{n-m}\right\}$

Comment: Oh okay , so is that the solution? For I thought the solution ha some value